# Docker compose is not creating a new volume

Tags: docker-compose, docker-volume

I am working with OpsWeb, which is built on different containers.

I would like to create a volume to link two folders: one inside the container called "opsweb-opsweb-backend-1", and the other inside the host VM, specifically in home/ubuntu/opsweb/exchange.

The problem is that the volume is not created, and I verified this on Portainer: the new volume is not appearing, and of course the link between the two folders is not working (meaning that I can't map a file that is created by the container into the folder of the host VM).

I followed the exact same syntax used for the previously defined volumes, which I link here:

[volumes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW0sQ.png)

The volume of interest is "exchange".

The container of interest is opsweb-backend, linked here:

[container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16ICQ.png)

Comment: Please add the codes in plain text not images as it is more readable and update the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with 'update_and_restart', the command that is generally used to restart the containers: it simply refresh the images, without taking into account new volumes that might be added from the docker-compose file.

So, in order to have compose to take into account volume mapping changes in the docker-compose.yml file, one has to run:
docker compose up --build <service_name> .